# How get values from postgres JSONB column?

Tags: json, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, jsonb, postgresql-10

I have PostgreSQL 10.5 database with Rails 5 application.

My model:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: property_keys
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  i18n_name  :jsonb
#

class PropertyKey < ApplicationRecord
  # Fields
  store :i18n_name, accessors: I18n.available_locales, coder: JSON
end
```

My migration:

```
class LocalizeProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    add_column :property_keys, :i18n_name, :jsonb

    PropertyKey.all.each do |property_key|
      [:en, :de, :ru].each do |locale_key|
        property_key.i18n_name[locale_key] = property_key.name
      end

      property_key.save!
    end
  end

  def down
    remove_column :property_keys, :i18n_name
  end
end
```

Table name: `property_keys`. List of fields:

- id: bigint
- i18n_name: jsonb

Here is a request for all data:

[image]

I want to get all english names (values of `"en"` key inside `i18n_name` column).

Here is a request:

```
SELECT
    id,
    i18n_name,
    i18n_name->'en' AS en
FROM property_keys;
```

And it returns nothing.

But theoretically should return the data with filled "en" column.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Also I tried query with `->>` and it did not work:

[image]

How should I change my request and which [PostgreSQL operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html) should I use to make it works?

Checked length of JSONB columns:

[image]

Comment: try using the `->>` operator?

Comment: Start with simplified autonomous example like `with t(x) as (values('{"en":"a","de":"b","ru":"c"}'::jsonb)) select x, x->'en' from t;` If it will work for you (it should) then try to find the difference.

Comment: @Abelisto query `with t(x) as (values('{"en":"a","de":"b","ru":"c"}'::jsonb)) select x, x->'en' from t;` works!

Comment: How connect this query with my table and get the data? And why actually magic with `->` and `->>` does not work?... According to Postgres Documentation it should..

Comment: I bet that the data you're seeing isn't really what is stored. Try the same data like this: `select '{"en":"asdasdadad","de":"asdasdadad","ru":"asdasdadad"}'::jsonb->'en'` If it works, your data contains some additional characters which you don't see.

Comment: @KamilG. but why PgAmin show this column as JSONB type?

Comment: I'm not saying it isn't JSONB. Though, please check by casting the column explicitly to this data type. I'm saying that there are characters probably inside `"en"` that you don't see. Try this: `select length(i18n_name::text), length('{"en":"asdasdadad","de":"asdasdadad","ru":"asdasdadad"}')` and see if it brings up the same number

Comment: @KamilG. awesome, attached new screenshot

Comment: @KamilG. so length of '{"en":"asdasdadad","de":"asdasdadad","ru":"asdasdadad"}' is 55 but in database 69 !

Comment: Ok, there is template for debugging: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4d7047d19bf7c911d757f5de8c79fa0c Just use your table/column names instead of the CTE. Note that the "bе" key in the JSONB object contains cyrillic letter "е" so its hexadecimal representation is different.

Comment: @bmalets told you there are characters you don't see. You can't extract `en` key if there is no such key. There lies your answer. Investigate the data to see what's inside or simply fix it by running an UPDATE

Comment: @KamilG. can you please write your last comment as the answer of question?

Comment: I changed my JSONB column to `{"q": "some text"}`. as "q" - is not cyrryllic character. And `->` magic begin to work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`->` and `->>` operators work as expected retrieving json object by key or as text in latter case.

The real issue that I suspect you have is that the data you're seeing isn't really what is stored inside your table which is why `i18_name->'en'` won't work since there is no key `en`.

To be able to confirm my writing please run below query to see if lengths of what you see in the string and what is stored inside a table match. They probably won't:

```
select
  length(i18n_name::text) AS stored,
  length('{"en":"asdasdadad","de":"asdasdadad","ru":"asdasdadad"}') AS whatisee
```

What you can do with it? Either investigate the data using `bytea` data type conversion or simply `UPDATE` the row with correct (what you see) data in this column.

This will make operators bring what you actually expect them to, since there will be `en` key within the jsonb field.

Answer (score 3):

For my case, in psql 11, both `->` and  `->>` work for both json and jsonb object.

`->` gets the value with double quotes (""), `->>` gets the value without double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You need [the `->>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html):

```
SELECT id,
       i18n_name,
       i18n_name->>'en' AS en
  FROM property_keys;
```

Comment: Just curious: why do you think that the `->>` operator will work where `->` operator  does not working?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not work... I attached a screenshot of PgAdmin query